# get row from excel driver using jdbc

Tags: database, excel, jdbc

i need to convert the sql statement to one which works in JDBC

```
"select * from [sheet1$] where [col1] = value1 and [col2] = value2"
```

ive searched diff sites n everywhere d statements are just "select * from [sheet$]" n havnt seen anyone use the where clause.
does it not work with excel driver?

Comment: It would be a good idea to post your connection string as it is important when considering column names.

Answer (score 0):

You can most certainly use a WHERE clause or any other Jet type SQL statement with Excel, and AFAIK, they work well with JDBC. One of the most common problems is the confusion with headers. If you have set the first row as headers, then they are your column names for the WHERE statement, if you have not, the the column names are F1, F2, ... Fn numbering from the first column of the selected range. In addition, if you are using headers but a column has a name that contains unacceptable characters, the Fn name will be used.